# Why doesn't a fluorescent lamp implode even though the pressure difference is very high?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, pressure

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Construction), the pressure inside a fluorescent lamp is 0.3% of the atmospheric pressure, so the pressure difference between the outside and the inside of the lamp is almost equal to the atmospheric pressure which is 1 bar or 14.7 psi.

Now according to [this](http://response.restoration.noaa.gov/oil-and-chemical-spills/chemical-spills/resources/overpressure-levels-concern.html) and [this](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=eH3OAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=glass%20shatters%20in%20psi&source=bl&ots=L1iBqXr_xk&sig=UCH5vSN7FGUbssYv3om12AFmCYU&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0w9nFhtnKAhVJWRoKHW9jCHk4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=glass%20shatters%20in%20psi&f=false), glass shatters at an overpressure of about 1 psi, and sometimes even less than that.

So why doesn't the difference in pressure between the outside and the inside of a fluorescent lamp cause the glass to shatter ?

Comment: @Bort Lava lamps?

Comment: @Brionius not sure what I read there.. seems like the drugs I never took finally take their price

Answer (score 3):

Due to the cylindrycal shape of the lamp, pressure forces act compresing the glass. Since the compressive strength of glass is quite high, [$\approx 10\,000$ bar](http://uk.saint-gobain-glass.com/trade-customers/physical-properties), atmospheric pressure is not enough to break it.

Comment: So if the shape of the lamp was rectangular, would it shatter ?

Comment: Yes, it would shatter.